# How to call a function in an iframe from the parent page?

Tags: jquery

How to call a function in an iframe from the parent page?

Comment: Same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672726/make-an-event-happen-in-child-iframe-to-the-parent-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 19):

As long as the framed page is on the same domain (or on a sub-domain, and you're setting document.domain), you need to access the *contentWindow* property of the frame element.  For example:

```
$("#myFrame")[0].contentWindow.myFunction();

// or, if jQuery hasn't made you lazy 
document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.myFunction();
```

Most browsers also support *contentDocument*, but Internet Explorer doesn't.  If your framed page is on a different domain then you'll get an Access Denied error.

Comment: I'd suggest that the non-lazy equivalent would *really* be `if(document.getElementById("myFrame").length==0){ document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.myFunction(); };`

Comment: @Jeromy: nope, both versions would throw the same error if `#myFrame` didn't exist in the same page.

Comment: I see what you mean...`$("#myFrame")[0]` returns `undefined`, which of course has no methods. I was thinking `$("#myFrame")...`, but that's not how this works. Thanks for setting me on the right path.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. I like the lazy version ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("iframe").each(function()
{
    $(this).one("load", function()
    {
        $(this)[0].contentWindow.myFunction();
    });
});
```

It is necessary to loaded iframe ;)

Answer (score 3):

Do it like a pro:

```
$("#myFrame").prop('contentWindow').abc();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try?

```
top.frames['my_frame'].myFunc();
```

Comment: It's javascript, you don't necessary need jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can select the iFrame using its id

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument
```

but I am not sure you can access its JavaScript,
especially if child iFrame is from different domain