# Calling a parent's function from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a function in an iframe from the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132411/how-to-call-a-function-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

How Call javascript function inside iframe  from parent?

Comment: no my function is in parent page

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is not from the same domain as the parent's page(including using the same protocol, and sub domain) then this isn't possible, but if from the same domain using the same protocol:

To call a function the parent has from the iframe:
`parent.functName()`

To call a function in the iframe from the parent:
`window.frames.iframeID.functName();`

Comment: in same domain.i write this but not work   parent.openPopup();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#iframeid').get(0).contentWindow.yourfunction()
```

that's the `jQuery` way

if you want to call a function in parent from the ifreme, just use

`window.top.yourfunction()`

Comment: no my function is in parent page

Comment: `How Call javascript function inside iframe from parent?` - that's your question ... tell us what's really you want to do?

Comment: Calling a parent's function from an iframe

Comment: see my edit of the answer: `window.top.yourfunction()`