# How to bind a function to a click on an iframe child

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to `hide` a `div` which is on an `iframe` on *iframes child click*.

`<a href="#" class="share">Share +</a>` -> this is the child I want to do some functions on **click**.

I used [this answers JQuery code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672858/1763929) but it doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="map_frame" frameborder="0" src="http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/vucko.map-1p4ens5h.html#17/45.80611110816038/15.924351969962727"></iframe>
<div>on "share +" click this div must hide so the share box goes above the div</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#map_frame').contents().find('.share').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Dge/1).

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done since the iframe document and the root document are from different domains. Browsers will not allow this, throwing a security exception.

For example, in chrome, this results in:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/vucko.map-1p4ens5h.html#17/45.80611110816038/15.924351969962727
>   from frame with URL http://fiddle.jshell.net/94Dge/1/show/. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

Comment: Yes, I saw the result. Is there some workaround to achieve my goal ?

Comment: The only solution in this particular case is that you server your application form `a.tiles.mapbox.com` or server the map from where your application's domain.

Comment: It's intresting that on my live page doesn't display any error. But it still doesn't work. EDIT: the error is still here.