# How to use javascript to locate and click an element in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe, webbrowser-control

Using Javascript in a webBrowser Control in a form, How do I switch to a iFrame

```
<iframe id="ContentFrame" class="contentIFrame" onload="checkComplementaryPage()" onmouseover="hoverMenu('dividers')"  name="ContentFrame" src="HomeContainer.aspx" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe><div id="footer" class="footer">
```

and then locate and click on an element inside that iFrame?

```
<div class="innerItem50L">
   <input type="submit" name="btnPunch" value="punch" id="btnPunch" style="CURSOR:hand;" />
</div>
```

I am new to programming and am starting with c#.  I know even less about Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Using the following thread as an example:

[Make an event happen in child iframe to the parent window in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672726/make-an-event-happen-in-child-iframe-to-the-parent-window-in-javascript)

You could do the following:

```
 $('#ContentFrame').contents().find('#btnPunch').click();
```

Note: The iframe's source has to be from the same domain, and contents must be loaded so you should put it after window load.

Comment: The frame is in the same domain, but is in a different sub-domain.  Is that alright?

Comment: Yes, just set the domain to the parent domain in the subdomains: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy#the-document-domain-exception

Comment: Is this in JavaScript or JQuery?  I am unable to implement this.  The "$" is showing an unexpected character and both of the # sections are showing as "Too many characters in character literal."

Comment: I think your comment about the domain and subdomains is based on me having access to the html.  I do not have this access.  Will this solution still work once I figure out how to implement JQuery into my code?

Comment: No. Javascript can only access web pages from the same origin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy