# iframe on a wordpress site that has a "next" button. I need to auto click that or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, mls

I thank anyone in advance for any assistance.

The website is alberniproperties.com. To access the Multi Listing Service and allow visitors to search the available up to date listing I pay for an iframe to give me that search functionality. However it has a long disclaimer at the beginning which I have feedback is deterring prospective home buyers from waiting after they press the agree button to reveal the attractive current listing with the option to refine the listing with different filters.

I would be so grateful if somehow that button to proceed to the listing pictures was auto pressed on the loading of the page so by the time the visitor scrolled to that part it would be all ready for them to use.

The website is hosted at godaddy as a managed wordpress if that is helps, please let me know if there is any thing further I can add to have someone assist me.

Thank you kindly

Comment: Duplicate question: [Make an event happen in child iframe to the parent window in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672726/make-an-event-happen-in-child-iframe-to-the-parent-window-in-javascript) and note the comment about domains.

Comment: I would advise to double check with the provider of the iframe to make sure auto-accepting the terms on behalf of your customers is not breaking the terms and conditions you have with them.

If it's fine for them to hide/remove those terms, they should be able to provide you, the paying customer with an iframe without those terms. But if they require the terms to be present and accepted, you might be trying to do something illegal here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I did speak to them and they are apologetic about having to have the legal stuff up first but they are contracted to have it there, it was them who suggested this is the solution that other customers had found acceptable, however as you can imagine that was all they could say on the matter, point me in the right direction then it was up to me to figure it out, which I'm not doing well at unfortunately

Comment: You can't access inside a cross domain iframe.

Comment: Ok thank you, it was worth a try. Maybe the help desk person I was speaking to was suggesting something else. I thought that is what they meant. sorry to bother everyone

Answer (score 0):

You have the iframe source, right?

Put that address in your browser bar, click the agree button and behold a new url. Can you use that url as your iframe src?