# Is there a way communicate from foreign webpage in iframe with my office Add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Add-in for outlook, that fetches the data from the email and perform its functionality.

Next, I am looking to have an iframe containing a webpage.

[image]

**Is there a way to make some kind of communication between the add-in and the webpage?**

**Use case:**

Let's say, Using office APIs I'll fetch the subject of the email, then I want the subject to be copied to google search (input), and from my search button (external see arrow) I could trigger the action.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because you still deal with a regular HTML document. Use `contents()` to access the `Document` object inside an `iframe`. For example:

```
$('[name=your_iframe]').contents().find('button').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

See [Attach an event in a child iframe to a handler in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672726/attach-an-event-in-a-child-iframe-to-a-handler-in-the-parent-window) for more information.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Is it the local host issue? what if I redirect my :3000 to ngrok?

Comment: See [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations).

Comment: You are suggesting to exchange data based on messages as mentioned  here https://johnresig.com/blog/cross-window-messaging/ ?

Comment: Is your query resolved??